# Problem accessing values globally due to event listener's function scope

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope, addeventlistener

Hello guys and thanks for the help.
`compileDescription` here is a function I called in order to create the description page of an ecommerce. I received the products passed as an argument from an api, deconstructed them and they work.
The main problem is that I passed the details of the matching product into the description and inserted them into the HTML DOM **within an event listener**. However, I need to manipulate the data I inserted into the DOM within the event listener within another function. For that, the `description` variable needs to be accessible outside the event listener, but even logging it into the console within the `compileDescription` function but outside the event listener returns an empty string.
**How do I make the values of `description` accessible both outside the event listener and outside the `compileDescription` function or in the global scope?**

```
    compileDescription(products){
        const eyeView = [...document.querySelectorAll('.view')]; //returns 16 buttons
        let description = '';
        
        eyeView.forEach(viewBtn=>{
        viewBtn.addEventListener('click', (event)=>{
        const btnId = event.target.dataset.class; //works and returns the ID
        const productFind = products.find(product=> product.id == btnId);  //returns an object with different properties and values
        description += `
            <article class="overDescription">
                <div class="descrContainer">
                    <div class="thisImage"> <img src="${productFind.image}" alt="">
                    </div>
                    <div class="productdetails">
                        <p class="prodescription">
                        ${productFind.description}
                        </p>
                        <h5 class="price"> #${productFind.price}</h5>
                        <button class="bag-btn" data-id= "${productFind.id}">
                            <img src="./images/icons8_add_shopping_cart_100px.png" 
                            width="16px" max-width= "18px" alt="add to cart"/>
                            Add to cart
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </article>
        `

        showDescription.innerHTML = description; //the page displays correctly with all its necessary features
        }) 
        })
        
        console.log(description); //returns an empty string
    }
```

Comment: Just place `let description;` outside the `compileDescription` function. The last `console.log` returns an empty string since that's the value of the variable in the moment you log, since you add `HTML strings` values only onclick.

Comment: @CesarePolonara Thanks for your response. Remember how I mentioned that this compileDescription is in a class? I can't declare a variable directly inside the class. But if I take the description variable way up to join with other variables I declared as global variables, the description variable returns undefined in the console even if I click on the button that's supposed to make it return the necessary values. I simply can't affect any variable outside the event listener with any result from within the event listener, but I need to for the program to work. Any idea how I can do this please?

Comment: ES10 introduced class fields : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields . In any case you can just simply save your variable as `this.description` and access it like that inside your class. If you need it outside the class. you can access it like `yourInstance.description` .